# Custom Pages and GUI extension with SDL Tridion 2011

Tags: tridion

Within the Content Manager Explorer (CME), I want to pass a value from an aspx page that includes multiple dropdownlists, populated relatively.

My aim is to return the last dropdown list selected value on clicking the submit button. For that I written javascript inside aspx page in script tag, but in the process of populating dropdownlists relatively the javascript is not returning value to the parent page. So I written a intermediate javascript file. So I need to send the selected value to Intermediate script file. Here my parent is nothing but Tridion page. Please suggest a way to acheive this. Thanks in advance. Early response is apprreciated.

Comment: At the moment, this question is difficult to answer. Please provide applicable code.

Comment: Please specify more structured info.  Need an example of the data source with list content, jQuery / Javascript sample with the relative dropdown code, and the Tridion GUI code that tries to update the Tridion page.  Also - please be specific about the 'Tridion Page' and GUI extension - what is the 'Tridion Page'?  Is it the popup you open from the ribbon or the Component Edit screen?

Answer (score 1):

Are you publishing the full .net page from SDL Tridion?

Typically what you would have is SDL Tridion publishing content and your .net application will pull this content into your page.

1) If you are publishing everything...

Simply put the javascript you need into your Tridion template (either the page or component template) whichever makes the most sense.

2) If you are using a dynamic page.   I suspect your view (razor file, master page etc) will be the most suitable place for you to include this additional javascript code.

As a final note if your javascript is contained in a function within a .js file, all you will really need to do update either 1 or 2 above to include a reference to your js file, and include a call to your javascript function.

I do hope you're building against option 2, in that your website presentation / application is outside of tridion, this makes the task of maintaining everything much easier.

Please let me know if this helps!

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not publishing the content.I am extending the ribbon tool bar. For that whenever i click a button on the ribbon toolbar I am opening an aspx page. My aim is to return the selected value from that aspx page to tridion page.

Comment: A tridion page in the CME? This would suggest the value needs to get to some metadata. Otherwise does the value need to get to a component field?

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to return your value too? A field within your page?

Anyway it seems like you are in need of some sort of GUI extension.   Jeremy has written a great tutorial, which I think is something that you are looking for, both where this example is within the component dialog, you'll need to tweak for the page dialog.

http://tridionfanboy.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/extending-the-sdl-tridion-2011-rich-text-field-format-toolbar/

His post deals with:

1) Putting something into the ribbon
2) The functionality on the item in the ribbon (your aspx page)
3) Putting that back into a tridion editing field (you need to return the value)

I hope this is useful to you.